# cannot open `' for reading: No such file or directory

Tags: shell-script, redhat-enterprise-linux

I am trying to run .sh file on RH6 and getting this error...

```
cannot open '' for reading: No such file or directory
```

The script I am running is internally referencing other scripts, located in same directory. I can see them using `ls -la`.

Note: This script is working perfectly fine on RH4. I got new fresh RH6 machine on which I am trying to run my scripts.

My `abc.sh` script as mentioned below

```
. fox_comm_server_details.sh
. fox_comm_topic_names.sh
. fox_comm_sh_tools.sh
```

refers to other script (`.sh`) files.

When I run my abc.sh (with `./abc.sh`) it says

```
fox_comm_server_details.sh: cannot open [No such file or directory]
```

I confirmed the required scripts are present in directory and I have permissions on them. 
If I update the `abc.sh` as below...

```
. ./fox_comm_server_details.sh
. ./fox_comm_topic_names.sh
. ./fox_comm_sh_tools.sh
```

This time it is not complaining about missing files but some different error as mentioned below...

> `read_fox_comm_servers_list[134]: read_fox_comm_servers_list_defaults[37]: local: not found [No such file or directory]`

`read_fox_comm_servers_list` and `read_fox_comm_servers_list_defaults` are functions that are defined in `fox_comm_sh_tools.sh` as follows...

```
function read_fox_comm_servers_list
{
        read_fox_comm_servers_list_defaults
        read_fox_comm_servers_list_overrides
}

function read_fox_comm_servers_list_defaults
{
        local tempfile=/tmp/read_fox_comm_servers_list_defaults.$$
}
```

and getting above mentioned error.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the script you are trying to run.

Comment: And provide the result of ls -l command. Also did you arr read permission to the script? They can't work w/o this permission

Comment: What is line 1 of your script. If it's `#!/bin/sh`, do you know what `/bin/sh` ***is*** on your system (e.g., is it bash or dash)? ... I guess that the `134` and `37` in the error message(s) are line numbers. You're probably right not to dump the entire 135+ line script on us, but have you tried deleting lines from (a working, debug copy of) the script until the error goes away? Try that -- the last thing you deleted will probably be a big clue to the problem.

Answer (score 0):

A shot in the dark:
please edit your question clicking [on this link](https://superuser.com/posts/875624/edit) because so it's really difficult to understand.

In general is seems that somewhere in a script (or in a subscript) a variable is not set with a filename.
You can notice from `''` without a name inside in your error message

> cannot open '' for reading: No such file or directory

You can search where is the error activating the [debug in your shell](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_02_03.html)

```
set -x           # to activate debugging  
./myscript.sh    # here your script invocation  
set +x           # to stop debugging
```

Comment: This won't quite work. Shell options (e.g., **xtrace**, or `-x` for short) are not passed from parent to child, so this will only say that the user is running `myscript.sh`, but not what happens _in_ the script. For that you would need one of the following: (1) `set -x; . myscript.sh; set +x` (probably not a good idea), (2) `(set -x; . myscript.sh)` (note the parentheses), (3) `sh -x myscript.sh`, or (4) edit `myscript.sh` and append `-x` to the she-bang line (the `#!/bin/sh` on the first line).